# Wordpress rewrite issue - 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having an issue with wordpress trying to rewrite a simple url-pattern to match my needs.

**Looking for:**

`How can I rewrite: localhost/projects/55/1 into index.php?page_id=X&proID=55&subID=1 without getting a 404?`

**What I tried so far:**

Modified .htaccess directly: does not work. Then I read some samples and tried it by calling the wordpress function add_rewrite_rule() on the init-hook. This is my current code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^projects/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?/?','index.php?page_id=8&proID=$matches[1]&subID=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT 1:**
[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, better. Now I dont get 404's anymore. But sadly, it is still not working (maybe I did something wrong).

```php
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_REQUEST); var_dump(get_query_var('proID')); var_dump(get_query_var('subID')); echo '</pre>';
```

Results in:

```php
array(0) {
}
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```

There is a page reload so it directs to `localhost/projects`.

Firebug:
`URL: http://10.0.0.109:8888/projects/25/2 Status: 301 Moved Permanently Domain: 10.0.0.109:8888 Size: 3.1 KB RemoteIP: 10.0.0.109:8888`

htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Custom rule
    RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?page_id=8&proID=$1&subID=$2 [L,QSA]
    
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the htaccess file again. You need to make sure to put this rule above the wordpress rules that may already be there:

```
RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page_id=8&proID=$1&subID=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please have a look at my "Edit 2". Cheers.

Comment: I am reviewing my old questions. Back then this did not solve my issue, but it had contributed to finding a solution. I will accept it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code. It might be solved your issue. I am not sure.

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^projects/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?/?','index.php?page_id=8&proID=$matches[1]&subID=$matches[2]','top');
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```